# Proper subclassing with Qt Creator forms?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, subclass

I'm trying to make a class (AgilentSweeper) which is a subclass of QDockWidget so that I can design the layout for it in Qt Creator's form designer.  The header for the class looks like this:

```
// agilentsweeper.h
#ifndef AGILENTSWEEPER_H
#define AGILENTSWEEPER_H

#include <QDockWidget>

namespace Ui {
class AgilentSweeper;
}

class AgilentSweeper : public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AgilentSweeper(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AgilentSweeper();

private:
    Ui::AgilentSweeper *ui;
};

#endif // AGILENTSWEEPER_H
```

and the source looks like

```
// agilentsweeper.cpp
#include "agilentsweeper.h"
#include "ui_agilentsweeper.h"
#include <QDockWidget>

AgilentSweeper::AgilentSweeper(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AgilentSweeper)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

AgilentSweeper::~AgilentSweeper()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

In my main class h file I declare an instance of AgilentSweeper with

```
#ifndef UTILSWEEP_H
#define UTILSWEEP_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include "agilentsweeper.h"

namespace Ui {
class UtilSweep;
}

class UtilSweep : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit UtilSweep(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~UtilSweep();

private:
    Ui::UtilSweep *ui;
    AgilentSweeper sweeper;
};

#endif // UTILSWEEP_H
```

And in the constructor for the main class I try to display "sweeper" on the side of the main window with

```
#include "utilsweep.h"
#include "ui_utilsweep.h"
#include "agilentsweeper.h"
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>

UtilSweep::UtilSweep(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::UtilSweep)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea,sweeper);
}

UtilSweep::~UtilSweep()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

However, I get an error that

```
In constructor 'UtilSweep::UtilSweep(QWidget*)':  utilsweep.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to 'UtilSweep::addDockWidget(Qt::DockWidgetArea, AgilentSweeper&)'
 addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea,sweeper);
```

with the hint that

```
candidates are:  void QMainWindow::addDockWidget(Qt::DockWidgetArea, QDockWidget*)
 void addDockWidget(Qt::DockWidgetArea area, QDockWidget *dockwidget);
```

Looking around, I found several other people with similar errors, but in their cases it seemed like either QDockWidget was not included in some places, or they were not using Q_OBJECT.  What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addDockWidget()` requires a pointer to a `QDockWidget` object as the second argument.  Your class variable `sweeper` is the object itself, not a pointer.  Your call to add `addDockWidget()` should be:

```
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, &sweeper);
```

Comment: I didn't check so could be wrong, but... doesn't the main window try to `delete` the dock widgets when its destructed? And since `sweeper` is not allocated with `new`, then this should crash when main window is destroyed at program exit.

Comment: See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects for details on declaring QObjects on the stack vs the heap.  Order is important.  The above works as the parent is declared prior to the child.  I tested to confirm.  The solution @hyde suggests, declaring `AgilentSweeper` with `new`, is the typical convention when declaring `QObjects`.

Comment: @esorton Mmm, yes. `sweeper` is member of `UtilSweep`, and therefore will get destructed (and remove itself as child of the object) before calling of `QObject` superclass destructor (which deletes remaining children).

Answer (score 2):

You should change the sweeper to be a pointer, and allocate it with `new`:

```
class UtilSweep : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
    AgilentSweeper *sweeper;
};
```

and

```
UtilSweep::UtilSweep(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::UtilSweep),
    sweeper(new AgilentSweeper(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, sweeper);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to allocate sweeper this way rather than later like `ui->setupUi(this);
    sweeper = new AgilentSweeper(this);`?